# How to close the previous window when a new window shows

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

This is my scenario:

My first window contains a ListView, each items in the ListView contain a button, if user click a button, a detail window shows.

I don't want the application shows too many window, only one is enough, if user click an item, the window shows, and when the user click another item, the content of the window changes, it doesn't create a new window to show. So I make the window as singleton, all of the content are using databinding (MVVM pattern), but if I close the window, the resource is disposed, so it will not show again, then I override closing method, let the window as cancel, not closed, but in this way, even I close the application, the window still not been disposed, there's also a process I can see in task manager.

Anybody has a more sensible idea? Thanks.

Edit:

```
 private void Window_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Window.Hide()`?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin Please see my override method, I have added it to initial post, thanks

Comment: I gathered you were doing that from the initial post, but I'm not sure why you're trying to hijack window closing and turn it into hiding. Why not `Hide()` the window instead of `Close()`ing it? Your current code will always prevent the window from closing normally.

Comment: Here in lies to major problem of MVVM. The answer is you can't DO window close with the Model. Consider either using Prism and regions. So you have a region adapter which when you remove the View from the adapter, the adaptor closes the window. OR you can consider using [MVPVM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh580734.aspx) (yeah, I thought it was a joke the first time I heard that)...

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin User may click 'X' button in the top right corner to close the window, then if he click another item, the window will not shows, an exception will be thrown. But if I don't use singleton pattern, if user click other item, a new window will be created, there will be a large number of window in memory.

Comment: I had some trouble understanding the question - I thought you wanted to hide the list window while another window was open. Have you tried hiding the close button?

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin If I hiding the close button, how to close the details window if user want to close it? Details window contains details content of the item in listview, if uesr want to see one item's detail, click it and the window appears, after completing reading the deatails, he could close it, and click other item to see, but he may not close it and click other item directly

Answer (score 0):

Try making a custom user control that can be loaded dynamically in run-time.
Example:

```
//constructor that builds a customer user control using a form as its argument
ItemControl control = new ItemControl(controlForm2);
//clear and load the user control to the panel of the form displayed
this.controlPanel.Controls.Clear();
this.controlPanel.Controls.Add(controlForm2);
```

However, this is not an appropriate way of handling this kind of control. You should make a form that receives parameters from the click event to generate the corresponding form based on what has user clicked in the list view.